# How do I compare lists made of SQL values, with other variables?

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to compare a variable with values from a SQL table. But, I'm having a lot of problems with it and I don't understand why.

I've already "imported" the values from the SQL table and put them into a list, using the code:

```
    cur= con.cursor()
    query= 'SELECT Username, Password FROM dbo.account_table'
    cur.execute(query)

    account_list = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        account_list.append(row)
```

And printing that list, gives this:

```
[('MTATQuestion', 'ComputerScience'), ('HarshMarker', 'harshmarker'), ('GuestAccount1', 'GuestPassword1'), ('GuestAccount2', 'GuestPassword2'), ('GuestAccount3', 'GuestPassword3')]
```

I've done all this, but here's where the problem starts. I want to check whether a user input is one of these values in the list, and if it is, to print("Access Accepted"). I'm using the code:

```
    UsernameInput = input("Enter your username: ")
    PasswordInput = input("Enter your password: ")
    for i in range(len(account_list)):
        if (UsernameInput, PasswordInput) == account_list[i]:
        print("Access Accepted")
```

However when I input the correct information, it doesn't do anything. I thought that the code just didn't work, but I made a test program using a list I made in python, with the same code, and it worked perfectly.

I'm not sure if this method just doesn't work with lists from SQL or if I'm just overlooking things. Any help would be appreciated, sorry for this particularly wordy "question".

EDIT: If it helps, the cause of the problem seems to be that (UsernameInput, PasswordInput) isn't recognised as a value inside the list (account_list).

Comment: You should print the values you're comparing inside the loop, then you'll be able to see what's going wrong. Note by the way that the loop is very unpythonic - there's rarely a reason to loop through "range(len(something))" and then access "something[i]" when you can just loop through "something" directly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your comment. I printed the user-inputted values and now I'm even more confused because they look the exact same as the values in the list, yet it still doesn't work. Also, I used range(len(account_list)) rather than range(account_list) because I needed to loop the same amount of times for how amount entries there were in the list, and account_list isn't an integer.

Comment: No that doesn't make sense. You need to loop through `account_list` - just like you loop through `cur.fetchall()` in the first snippet. It's not supposed to be an integer, it's a list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hey, I tried doing this method but it restricted me to only be able to use integer values in account_list[], rather than account_list[i], and it still didn't work even after that. I've tried other methods like separating the Username and Password into 2 different lists, but nothing has worked so far. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
for i in range(len(account_list)):
    if (UsernameInput, PasswordInput) == account_list[i]:
        print("Access Accepted") # check your indentation above!
```

Remove the for loop and try the more concise form

```
    if (UsernameInput, PasswordInput) in account_list:
        print("Access Accepted")
```

Edit:

That code has to work, see the interactive session below:

```
>>> accounts = [('Demo', 'demo'), ('Mary', 'butterfly')]
>>> UsernameInput = 'Mary'
>>> PasswordInput = 'butterfly'
>>> if (UsernameInput, PasswordInput) in accounts:
...     print('Access accepted')
... 
Access accepted
```

Comment: This solution didn't work. I have tried using the in operator, but the inputs still aren't recognised as being inside the list. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @MTATQuestion see my edit. Also from your question, there are no SQL lists as such. You either get tuples or a list of tuples from the fetch methods. Maybe you are comparing tuples with lists by mistake? Not having any other idea... but " they look the exact same as the values in the list" looks strange to me.

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work but I managed to get it through an alternative method. You mentioning that it may be a list of tuples got me to realise that's what it was (I'm not very smart). This led me down the rabbit-hole of itertools.chain, which I attempted to use to success. While, it wasn't your code which specifically helped me, you're still the reason why I got mine working, so I'll accept your answer anyway.